# Erro no array em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou colocando um script da zanox no meu site para fazer retargeting de produtos em um e-commerce.

Quando coloco o script para puxar variáveis isoladas tudo funciona, mas quando preciso puxar as variáveis dentro de um Array, não funciona.

Segue o script que está certo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var zx_identifier = "<%=RSProdutoDetalhe("Codigo")%>",
var zx_fn = "<%=RSProdutoDetalhe("Nome")%>",
var zx_category = "<%=RSProdutoDetalhe("Categoria")%>"
</script>
```

Segue o script que está errado:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var zx_products = [{
"zx_identifier" : "<%=RSProdutoDetalhe("Codigo")%>",
"zx_amount" : "<%=PrecoProdutoCarrinho%>",
"zx_currency" : "BRL",
"zx_quantity" : "<%=RSPedidoTempGrade("Quantidade")%>"
}];
</script>
```

Depois precisaria fazer um loop para pegar todos os eventuais produtos da página dentro desse array

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigado

Comment: Qual erro é gerado?

Comment: ¿não teria que ser "zx_amount":"<%=PrecoProdutoCarrinho("Preco")%>"

Comment: A linguagem usada entre os _tokens_ `<%=` e `%>` é PHP ou outra coisa? Não conheço esse zanox...

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o JSON.stringify, segue:

```js
var zx_products = JSON.stringify({
"zx_identifier" : "<%=RSProdutoDetalhe("Codigo")%>",
"zx_amount" : "<%=PrecoProdutoCarrinho%>",
"zx_currency" : "BRL",
"zx_quantity" : "<%=RSPedidoTempGrade("Quantidade")%>"
});
```

Mais detalhes: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp